Discrepancy Between KS Test Results and CDF Visualizations in Neuronal Correlation Analysis
Discrepancy Between KS Test Results and CDF Visualizations in Neuronal Correlation Analysis
I am analyzing Pearson Correlation Coefficient (PCC) values computed pairwise for a set of neurons measured across different days, focusing then on a subset we can call "Cells X". My goal is to determine whether these Cells X exhibit significantly higher PCC values compared to the other neurons.
Methodology:

PCC Calculation: I computed the PCC values for all neuron pairs.
CDF Plotting: I plotted the cumulative distribution functions (CDFs) of the PCC values for both Cells X and the remaining neurons to visually compare their distributions.
Statistical Testing: I applied the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test to assess whether there are significant differences between the two distributions.

Observations:
While the KS test yielded very small p-values, indicating significant differences between the distributions, visual inspection of the CDF plots suggests that the distributions are almost identical, leaving me very confused regarding the interpretation of these results.

Questions:

Sensitivity of the KS Test: Is it common for the KS test to produce significant results when visual assessments indicate similarity? What could be causing this discrepancy?
Alternative Approaches: Given this situation, what alternative statistical methods or visualizations would you recommend to more accurately assess the differences between these two groups?

I appreciate any insights or recommendations on how to proceed with this analysis.

Your 2 ECDF's look a) indeed very close b) but also very smooth, which is unexpected, at least for small-ish sample sizes. How many datapoints in your 2 samples? If it is very large, that may be the reason (2 samples K-S is more sensitive the larger the sample sizes). So maybe?

It has ~23500 samples each. It is indeed a lot, yes.
In theory, I can subsample it by randomly choosing only some of the samples but it doesn't make sense to me, as I am basically "choosing" the p-value I like in such a case. So I am quite confused about how one should approach this.

There's absolutely no mystery here: The power of the KS-test approaches 1 with increasing sample size (in statistical jargon: the test is consistent). So you have a lot of power to detect even miniscule differences. The fact that you're uncomfortable with a small p-value despite small visual differences indicates that you're not really interested in a test but an effect size of the difference with an uncertainty interval. If you're interested in a test you already have your answer: There's a lot of evidence that the distributions differ.

The reason is your very large sample size (~23500). This is closely related to the fact that, given any 2 populations, one can always find a sample size large enough so that the test (pretty much any test; t-test, $\chi^2$, Mann-Whitney-U, K-s, etc.) will return a significant p-value. See this CV post, or this one. When $n$ becomes very large, the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of your statistic becomes very small (i.e. the error on the estimate of your statistic becomes very small), and if there is an effect, no matter how small, you can find a sample size which detects it. Since, in the real world, point nulls are basically always false (and $F=G$ is such a point null), this is your issue: you have achieved a sample size where K-S detects an effect, even though it seems very small.
What K-S is telling you is that no, the 2 distributions are not exactly the same; and with a large sample size, even a small difference can no longer be attributed to "chance". So the K-S test is telling you the truth.
Now, your eyes are telling you that the 2 distributions are very close; indeed from a distance, they overlap perfectly. But if you look closer, you can see that Cells X are stochastically dominant to the other cells ($G\ge F$ everywhere, and in some places $G>F$).
You could convince yourself that this is due to the sample sizes by subsampling from your samples; start e.g. with 100 samples each. Then go to 500, 1000, 10,000, etc. until you get a significant result. Alternatively, you could decide to do a form of bootstrap; pick a subsample size (e.g. 300?), and keep taking random subsamples, run the K-S test, and see how often you get a significant result. It should be around $100.\alpha \%$.
Now you may ask "which do I believe? K-S (which is technically corrrect) or my eyes?". That may not be the right question; the proper question should be "who cares?". That is, while indeed the 2 distributions are not exactly the same, does anyone care about such a small difference? Does it matter for whatever your research question is? Only you, and domain experts can answer this.
Now, you could also compute the effect size for the K-S test; see How do I calculate the effect size for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Z statistic?. This will quantify the effect, and you may be able to determine if this effect is practically significant or not (but it is not the most obvious to interpret; "supremum"?).
Alternatively you could also run a simple t-test (which almost for sure will also be significant for the same reason), and look at the effect size (difference of means. Do you care about that difference?
